# How do I connect UITabBar items from a UITabBar (not a UITabBarController) to different views in the IB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I’ve created a StoryBoard project and added a `UITabBar` to my first view and a few `UITabBar` items on it. I’m using a `UITabBar` and not a `UITabBarController` because the `UITabBar` needs to be scrollable vertically so it is inside a `UIScrollView`. I want to connect the `UITabBar` items to different `ViewControllers`. How do I do that inside the Interface builder?

With `UITabBarController` it’s just a Ctrl+drag like everything else in the IB, but for some reason the `UITabBar` acts differently. I’m aware of all the delegation methods I need to implement, but for now I’m only interested on how to connect the `UITabBar` items to the views.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
firstViewController.tabBarItem = firstItem;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a IB way to do that

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably after is [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You generally don't want to manage a `UITabBar` manually.

If you're using storyboards, you can drag out a `UITabBarController` and then Ctrl-drag from it to other view controllers in the storyboard to link them to the `viewControllers` property.

Comment: Like the title mentioned, I don't want to use UITabBarController. I want to use UITabBar.

Comment: @Sha is there a reason you can't use a tab bar controller? You're right though, I missed that in the title.

Comment: Yes, the tabBar needs to be scrollable.

Comment: @Sha ok, that would be helpful to have in the question. What do you mean by it needs to be scrollable? Is it inside a scroll view that scrolls vertically?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-HcdK_Sdmw&feature=youtu.be  also edited the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. From `UITabBar` item ctr+drag to your next `ViewController` (select style push, modal).
2. Give you `UITabbarItem` tags.
3. Import `UITabBarDelegate` to your Controller.
4. Add following delegate method

   ```
   - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
   {
       if (item.tag==0) {
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Favorite" sender:nil];
       }
       else if (item.tag==1)
       {
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Item" sender:nil];
       }
   }
   ```

   5. Give identifier for each segue.

you can get my demo from following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrgv7s4mmf4w196/DemoTable%202.zip)

but problem is that `tabbar` will not appear on next `ViewController`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Connecting the view to another view and setting their tag isn't really the IB way I was looking for. I was looking for a way to connect the UITabBar item to the view. Also the fact that that `UITabBar` appears only in the first view makes it unusable.