# How do i connect UITabBar items to view controllers in IB

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uitabbar

I want to connect `UITabbar` items to different view controllers. I dont want to use `UITabBarController`. I have a `UITabBar` in a `ViewController`. I am aware of the delegate methods also. Just wanted to know if there is a way to do this through the interface builder(Ctrl+Drag way). Ctrl+Drag only works for elements in `UITabBarController` and not for `UITabbar`.

PS: Same question has been asked before but re-posting because there is no satisfactory answer for this. 
[How do I connect UITabBar items from a UITabBar (not a UITabBarController) to different views in the IB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962043/how-do-i-connect-uitabbar-items-from-a-uitabbar-not-a-uitabbarcontroller-to-di)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really sorry. But the fact is that you can't.

`UITabBar` is a subclass of `UIView`. Better use `UITabBarController` . It will provide you a base controller class  and works as a container for rest of your controllers.